# Subclass to map additional column of table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have entity class *A* and Fluent NHibernate map for it *AMap* which maps some columns from database table (a few fields are missing). I would like to create class *B* which inherits from *A* (to not break relations with other entities) and map for it to allow access to columns not mapped by base class. The problem is that I cannot change any line of code in base classes (*A* and *AMap*). Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure how you wanna use it but this could do

```
class B : A
{

}

class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMap()
    {
        Table("A's tablename");
        ...
    }
}
```

then this should be possible

```
someEntity.ListOfAs.Add(new B());
```

dont know if there are problems down the road though

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I had to copy all mappings from AMap to BMap but this is what I can do

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the requirement, this is a simple [table per class hierarchy](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tableperclass) mapping. You'll need a discriminator column for that.

For the mapping see the last example on that page: [Fluent Wiki](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#Subclasses).

Comment: The problem is diffrent and table per class hierarchy won't work here.